# Why isn't my POST XMLHttpRequest.Send working?

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I am having issues correctly setting up my XMLHttpRequest object to POST data to a server. The data (from an HTML form) never seems to get posted, or at least **readyState** == 4 && **status** are never reached.

```
    function PostToAPI() {

        var payersName = document.forms["myForm"]["payersName"].value;  
        var recipientPhoneNumber = document.forms["myForm"]["recipientPhoneNumber"].value;
        var apiKey = document.forms["myForm"]["apiKey"].value;  

        var params = "payersName="+payersName+
                     "&recipientPhoneNumber="+recipientPhoneNumber+  
                     "&apiKey="+apiKey;         

        alert(params);  // Note#1

        var Url = "https://api.blackShawls.af/c2b"; // Note#2
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', Url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

        function processRequest(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)  {
                alert(xhr.responseText.headers.Host); // Note#3
            }
        }

        xhr.send(params);

    }
```

#### Notes

1. (Note#1) This alert yields the following result:
   [image: the result shown from this alert]

   This suggests that the various fields from the HTML form have been successfully read in, and that everything is working just fine to this point.
2. (Note#2) The **Url** value here is fictitious, in contrast to one in my code.
3. (Note#3) The `alert(xhr.responseText.headers.Host);` never seems to fire-up, suggesting that the `readyState` and the `status` conditions are never met.

   Or could it be that the `xhr.send(params)` is never sent?

Can someone kindly point out where I am going wrong in my code?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what's being sent and received in the AJAX request.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Did you even bother to check before posting? The first step of debugging should always be to fix errors that are reported.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the prompt. To answer your question I actually checked the console before posting. And it's totally blank. No errors! Though am not too conversant with the tool in the network tab, I can say it displays that its posted the parameters, but I cant tell if I have gotten a response or not.

Comment: Click on the AJAX request URL, and you should see a Response tab that will show what you got in the response.

Comment: GOogle "debugging ajax in chrome" and you'll find some tutorials, including some videos.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tips on how to debug in Chrome. Sadly the only methods I've noticed during the Chrome debug is the GET methods. I expected at least one POST method

Comment: Put a `console.log` call right before `xhr.send(params)` to make sure you're getting there.

Comment: Or just single-step in the debugger.

Comment: BTW, get in the habit of using `console.log` rather than `alert`, as it doesn't block the execution.